# Redirecionar uma rota de um "childModule" para outro "childModule" com o Angular 2 (^4.0)

Tags: angular, angular-routes

Olá, estou trabalhando com o Angular onde eu tenho uma estrutura como esta:

```
|-app
   |-fooModule (fooPage1, fooPage2)
   |-barModule (barPage1, barPage2)
```

Esses dois módulos estão sendo carregados usando `lazyLoad` no arquivo de rotas como mostra a seguir:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'bar', loadChildren: './foo/foo.module#FooModule' },
    { path: ''   , loadChildren: './bar/bar.module#BarModule' }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

O módulo `AppRoutingModule` é carregado no módulo inicial do projeto, o `AppModule` juntamente com outros, e tanto em **foo** quanto em **bar** a mesma estrutura mas, ao invés de carregar módulos com lazyLoad, eu carrego componentes, assim:

**exemplo: foo-routing.module (bar-routing.module.ts tem a mesma estrutura)**

```
import { FooPage1Component } from './foo-page-1/foo-page-1.component';
import { FooPage2Component } from './foo-page-2/foo-page-2.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'page2', component: FooPage2Component },
    { path: ''   , component: FooPage1Component }
];
```

Meu problema é que, quando eu estou na rota *www.meusite.com/page2* e tento forçar um roteamento para o BarModule, o Angular não remove os componentes já carregados do FooPage2Component. É como se ele nao desse update no `<router-outlet>`. A forma que faço a chamada para outro módulo pode ser vista no componente FooPage2Component:

**foo-page-2.component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'foo-page-2',
    templateUrl: './foo-page-2.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./foo-page-2.component.scss']
})
export class FooPage2Component {
    constructor(
        private router:Router
    ){
        // depois de 2 segundos, redirecione para o módulo bar na pagina 2
        setTimeout(()=> router.navigate(['../bar/page2']), 2000);
    }
}
```

Quando eu compilo o código acima, e faço o teste, o resultado na minha página ao fazer o redirecionamento fica assim:

**estrutura renderizada no navegador**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <app>
             <router-outlet></router-outlet>
             <foo-page-2></foo-page-2>
             <bar-page-2></bar-page-2>
        </app>
    </body>
</html>
```

Então aqui vai a pergunta: se eu tenho 2 módulos diferentes que tem suas próprias rotas e são carregados dinamicamente (com lazyLoad no loadChildren) como eu posso dizer ao angular que eu quero, a partir do componente FooPage2 que está no FooModule, redirecionar para um componente BarPage2 no BarModule?

> **Nota:** já tentei usar o [Router.navigate](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate), [Router.navigateByUrl](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate), já tentei forçar a navegação passando os parâmetros do [NavigationExtra.relativeTo](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#relativeTo) e mesmo assim, não funciona. Infelizmente minha solução até o momento está sendo um (horrível) `window.location.href = window.location.href.replace('/page2','/bar/page2)`;

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como não houve nenhum tipo de resposta e, também não encontrei uma solução plausível na internet, minha solução foi criar um serviço que está relacionado ao component `AppComponent` e que fica escutando um evento customizado. Esse evento customizado simplesmente dispara o array que a referencia do [`Router`](https://angular.io/guide/router) precisa para conseguir fazer o redirect sem sair do angular, assim todo o controle de redirecionamento é feito pelo módulo principal independente do módulo filho que eu usar assim:

**Classe RootRouterRedirect.ts**

```
export class RootRouterRedirect {

    public constructor(redirect: string | string[]) {
        const event = new CustomEvent('rootRouterRedirect', { detail: [].concat(redirect) });
        window.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

}
```

E no meu AppComponent eu anexei um método que faz o listener desse evento, assim:

**AppComponent**

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
... outros imports 
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {

    ... construtores e métodos

    @HostListener('window:rootRouterRedirect', ['$event'])
    private event(e): void {
        this.router.navigate(e.detail);
    }

}
```

> **Porque fazer isso?**
>
> O Angular 2 permite que se tenha múltiplos arquivos de rotas sendo
>   cada um em cada módulo. Essas rotas podem ter seus redirecionamentos
>   mas, pelo que percebi quando se direciona rotas entre módulos
>   carregados via [`lazyload`](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html) como na descrição do problema, a estrutura
>   de rotas não consegue destruir corretamente todos os componentes,
>   mantendo assim trechos, rastros ou em ocasiões a própria rota sem
>   atualizar.
>
> Agora se caso quem fizer a chamada for a rota que trabalha sobre o
>   `RouterModule.forRoot()`, esse problema não ocorre porque ele é que
>   faz o tratamento principal. Além disso, parece que se o módulo não
>   está carregado (porque ser um módulo lazyload) a sub-estrutura do
>   `RouterModule.forChild()` que está definida nele ainda não é
>   encontrada, portanto não pode ser referenciada.